# How to increase the height of the custom cell in UITableView when screen size increased?

Tags: swift

How to increase the height of the custom cell in UITableView when screen size increased?

iPhone 7 plus view:
[image: iPhone 7plus view]

iPhone 5s view:
[image: iPhone 5s View]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `HeightForRowAtIndexPath` and return the height you want for each device type.

Comment: If my answer solved you issue please accept it as an answer